# Display custom field of variable product in tab "additional_information"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display the meta-field "_ts_gtin" of a variable product within the tab "additional_information" of a single product.

I just figured out that I can get the value of a specific variation this way:

```
get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], '_ts_gtin', true )
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your functions.php or plugin:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'print_variation_html' );

function print_variation_html($product){
    $variations_id = $product->get_variation_id();   

    if(!$variations_id) return;

    $variation_meta = get_post_meta( $variations_id , '_ts_gtin', true );
    print_r( $variation_meta );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it's not working. Nothing happens, if I add that action.

Comment: Forgot we had to the variation ID in that scope. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Add the follows code snippet to do the above -

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', 'add_info_in_product_additional_information', 99 );

function add_info_in_product_additional_information( $product ) {
    if( $product ) {
        $children_ids = $product->get_children();
        if( $children_ids ) {
            echo '<ul id="variation-gtin">';
            foreach ( $children_ids as $v_id ) {
                echo '<li class="item-'.$v_id.'">#' . $v_id . ': ' . get_post_meta( $v_id , '_ts_gtin', true ) . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
}

// scripts
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_scripts_on_found_variation' );

function add_scripts_on_found_variation() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ( function( $ ) {
            $( 'form.variations_form').on( 'found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
                $( '#variation-gtin .item-'+variation.variation_id ).show().siblings().hide();
            } );
        } )( jQuery );
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Codes goes to your active theme's functions.php

Comment: Thanks, thats basically working but I'd like to only display the GTIN of the currently selected child-product

Comment: @ManuKILLED as per your requirements you have to apply some scripts over above scripts to do so. Anyway I updated my code along with the scripts. Please check.